# How to return true or false in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I want to compare the number of edges around a  with a number and print `true` or `false`, something like this:
`g.V().out().count()==0`
but `==` didn't work here, it always return `false`.
Is there a alternative way?

Answer (score 5):

What is returned by the last count() step is a traversal, which provides an iterator interface that can be used to retrieve results.

If your goal is to count all the out edges of all the vertexes in the graph, return that single number, and compare that to 0, this will work:

```
gremlin> g.V().out().count().next()==0
==>false
```

If your goal is to do comparisons to 0 within the Gremlin language, the is() step can be used to test a number for equality:

```
gremlin> g.V().out().count().is(0)
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
```

If you want to print the boolean results:

```
gremlin> g.V().choose(out().count().is(0), constant(true), constant(false))
==>false
==>true
==>true
==>false
==>true
==>false
```

Or maybe return maps with each vertex and its test result?

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').choose(out().count().is(0), constant(true), constant(false)).as('b').select('a','b')
==>[a:v[1],b:false]
==>[a:v[2],b:true]
==>[a:v[3],b:true]
==>[a:v[4],b:false]
==>[a:v[5],b:true]
==>[a:v[6],b:false]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply chain `.hasNext()` to you `Traversal`, since it's an iterator.

Starting from a blank graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices: 0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices: 0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasNext()
==>false
```

Let's add a single vertex

```
gremlin> g.addV('name', 'Alice')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().out().hasNext()
==>false
gremlin> g.V().hasNext()
==>true
```

Comment: I was using this only. But, the issue is that, consider we have only vertex with id (id-1) and when u pass ID's like 
g.V('id-1','id-2').hasNext() it is returning true only. It works only when find single vertex/edge